# Unity normalize function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to shoot bullets in the direction of my mouse.But the closer the mouse is to my gun , the slower the bullets go.So I thought I should normalize my vector:

```
Vector3 shootDirection = (mousePosition - shootpoint.transform.position);
 shootDirection.Normalize();
```

From what I know , after normalizing a vector , its x and y will follow the pythagorean theorem:

```
x^2 + y^2 = 1
```

However , if I debug my vector coordinates after normalizing , I get this:

```
0,1915651 0,1933651
0,5729401 0,4919207
```

which clearly don't follow the rule.Any help?

Comment: how are you printing that? because a `Vector3` has **3** components ...

Comment: debug.log(shootDirection.x + " " + shootDirection.y)

Comment: Yeah as said .. `Vector3` has x,y,z and these together are 1 ...maybe you want `Vector2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said and as the name suggests a [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) has **3** components x, y, z.

If you are only interested in x and y you should rather use a [`Vector2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html) and normalize that one:

```
var shootDirection = (mousePosition - (Vector2)shootpoint.transform.position). normalized;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sort of right about the pythagorean theorem. Normalizing means that the `magnitude` of the resulting vector will be 1. (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html)

I can't tell from your example, but you might need to store the value of the vector3 first before printing it. Maybe make your code:

`Vector3 shootDirection = (mousePosition - shootpoint.transform.position).normalized;`

And see if the shootdirection is more what you'd expect?

If not, what input are you using, and then what output?

Comment: I got it now.I should have changed vector3 to vector2.